# How to properly set margins in a base R figure with multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I consulted multiple tutorials, YouTube videos, StackOverflow threads, but couldn't figure out what to do to properly visualize 9 plots in the same image, without squeezing/resizing them.

Here is my code, can anyone help visualizing them appropriately?

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0), 5, 2, byrow = TRUE))

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

for(k in 1:9){
  dat <- rnorm(200)
  hist(dat, prob = T,
       main = substitute(paste("Empirical distribution of"),
                     list(h=c(1:9)[k])),
       xlab = substitute(beta[h],
                     list(h=c(1:9)[k])))

  lines(density(dat),lwd = 2)
}
```

As you can see from the image below, the result looks quite messy!

[image]

Edited:

If I increase the margins with, for example:

```
par(mar=c(4, 2, 1.5, 0.5))
```

The xlab and ylab are displayed correctly, but it looks like the histograms get "squeezed" to fit inside the remaining available space... Is there any option I could use to preserve the original size of the histograms? I don't understand what am I missing here...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't fully understand what `mar` means. It refers to the number of text lines reserved on "bottom", "left", "top" and "right" for each subplot (that is, clockwise order from "bottom").

I usually find `par(mar=c(2, 2, 1.5, 0.5))` comfortable, which gives a compact display without showing `xlab` and `ylab`. But if you want to see `xlab` and `ylab`, you need to increase margin and use `par(mar=c(4, 4, 1.5, 0.5))`.

Below is the figure used for **R**'s official manual:

[image: mar]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, I understood what you explained, the problem is: the more I increase the margins so that xlab and ylab are visible, the more the plots are "squeezed" to fit inside the remaining available space (see new picture in my question). Is there any option I can use to preserve the size of the histograms?

Comment: @supertrip86 So you think the "original size" is the 0 margin case? This is sort of a paradox unfortunately; with no margin how to display annotations? In R base plotting system, we can at most squeeze margin to `mar = c(2.5, 2.5, 1.5, 0.5)` then fit annotations (axes and axes labels) into this margin space. But still, we need margins if we want to display annotations. In general, when the overall figure size is fixed, the more subfigures you have, the smaller each one will be, right?

Comment: Hi Zheyuan Li, thank you for your help. I guess I will try to go for a different solution then.

Comment: @supertrip86 Although GG plotting system with `ggplot2` is quite popular these days, I think for your purpose, the grid plotting system with `lattice` is better. I also plan to dig into `lattice`. I have been a long time R base plotting system user. It can work beautifully, but just require lines of code to tweak axes positions, label positions, etc, for the best presentation effects.